# How to use jsonSerialization with objectbox Entity class

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, json-serialization

I am facing issue when I am using **JsonSerialization on Objectobox Entity**
I tried to find better solution but I could not find

Comment: Please provide more details, this question can‘t be answered with the provided info.

Comment: We have a test that uses `json_serializable`, maybe that can help you get started: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/blob/main/generator/integration-tests/part-partof/lib/json.dart

Answer (score 0):

```
@JsonSerializable()
@Entity()
class ContactModel {
  @Id()
  int internalId;
  @Index()
  final String? id;
  final String? userId;
  final String? businessName;
  final String? contactPersonName;
  final String? contact;
  final String? whatsappNumber;
  final String? email;
  final String? address;
  final String? pinCode;
  final String? city;
  final String? businessType;
  final String? description;
  final String? img;
  final String? lat;
  final String? longitude;
  final String? createDate;
  final String? clientType;

  ContactModel(
      {this.internalId=0,
      this.id,
      this.userId,
      this.businessName,
      this.contactPersonName,
      this.contact,
      this.whatsappNumber,
      this.email,
      this.address,
      this.city,
      this.pinCode,
      this.businessType,
      this.description,
      this.img,
      this.lat,
      this.longitude,
      this.createDate,
      this.clientType});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(ContactModel contactModel) => _$ContactModelToJson(contactModel);

  factory ContactModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ContactModelFromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).